# array in foreach is always empty after foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, laravel, foreach

I was trying to create an array to show chart. Below is my data[image]

here  is my code to create 2d array.

```
$chart = [];
    foreach ($results as $data) {
        $chart["Label"][] = $data->monthly;
        $chart["Paid"][$data->monthly] = 0;
        $chart["Overdue"][$data->monthly] = 0;
        $chart["Due"][$data->monthly] = 0;
        $chart[$data->status][$data->monthly] = $data->total_invoices;
    }
    return $chart;
```

but my results isn't as expected.

I want the first array that contains 4 array with key as paid, Due, Overdue, and Label. and if there is no any output from results "i.e. for month "2022-05" has only "Due" amount,there is no Overdue, and Paid",it should place 0 for that.

but the overdue array is always 0

Actual Result:

```
Overdue": {
    "2022-05": 0,
    "2022-04": 0,
    "2022-03": 0,
    "2022-02": 0,
    "2022-01": 0,
    "2021-12": 0,
    "2021-11": 0,
    "2021-10": 0,
    "2021-09": 0,
    "2021-08": 0
},
```

Expected result

```
Overdue": {
    "2022-05": 0,
    "2022-04": 51,
    "2022-03": 9,
    "2022-02": 3,
    "2022-01": 1,
    "2021-12": 0,
    "2021-11": 0,
    "2021-10": 0,
    "2021-09": 0,
    "2021-08": 0
},
```

Comment: Because you're hardcoding the value `0` -> `$chart["Overdue"][$data->monthly] = 0;`

Comment: yes but the last line is overwriting the data with the original value that is coming from the data

Comment: Not for `"Overdue"`, but for `$data->status`

Comment: $data->status values are either Paid, Due, Overdue. Please check the data above. foreach is working on results above

Comment: your array loop looks fine you should look into your `total_invoices` getter

Comment: Where is `total_invoices` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the values on every loop, can change your script like this to prevent it:

```
    $chart = [];
    foreach ($results as $data) {
        $chart["Label"][] = $data->monthly;
        $chart["Paid"][$data->monthly] ??= 0;
        $chart["Overdue"][$data->monthly] ??= 0;
        $chart["Due"][$data->monthly] ??= 0;
        $chart[$data->status][$data->monthly] = $data->total_invoices;
    }
    return $chart;
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the issue. And I was using ternary operator `? :` but your code is much clean and understandable

Comment: @ajaychawla Where were you using a ternary ? Not in the code you showed us?